# Analyzing text/instruction segment size

Tags: linux, memory, process

I am investigating on the use of RAM of a C++ program I am developing.
When launched, it consumes a RES memory of 680MB.

Observation 1 :
I just added a sleep(1000) at the beginning of the main() function to see the initial consumption. The RES memory is very small (some KB) while the VIRT memory is about 630MB.

Observation 2 :
By compiling a very simple program with just an infinite loop while(1) {}, I have got VIRT = 4KB and RES < 1KB.

My understanding 1 (after some research) :
Text/instruction memory segment is stored at the beginning of the virtual memory range. So, Linux needs to reserve that space as soon as it launches a process. It doesn't load all binary in physical memory on launch (hence the small RES in observation 1) but only when necessary. But it needs to reserve the virtual range for the instruction/text memory segment as the heap segment comes just after and those segments needs to fit in a continuous memory range. True ?

Understanding 2 :
The high VIRT memory in observation 1 is reserved for storing the instruction segment of my program. In observation 2, the binary file is small and there is no dynamic library. That is why it allocates a small virtual memory. True ?

Understanding 3 :
The instruction/text memory segment will store the code from my program binary files and the one from my dynamic libraries. True ?

Understanding 4 :
Linux can know the maximal total amount of instruction/text memory on launch.

Question : How can I know the detail of the binary files (executable and dynamic libraries) requirement in term of memory. Following my understanding 4, Linux can do it to reserve the virtual memory range. Can I have access to the details of this calculus. Of course, I need this information to identify which library is that big and how I could reduce the memory usage of my program.

Thank you for your help !!

Comment: Just wanted to know how are you measuring RES and VIRT?

Comment: Sorry, RES and VIRT are the memory as reported by a tool like top. RES is the physical memory addressed by the process (it can be shared with other) while VIRT is the virtual memory range.